# What is wrong with this python code to compute a food bill?

Tags: python

I've been doing a course on Codecademy and it gave me this task:

> Define a function `compute_bill` that takes one argument `food` as input.
>   In the function, create a variable `total` with an initial value of zero.
>   For each item in the `food` list, add the price of that item to `total`.
>   Finally, return the total.

This is my code:

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total=0
    for x in food:
        total+=x
    return total
```

and this is the error they gave me:

> compute_bill(['apple']) resulted in a TypeError: unsupported operand
>   type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

I don't know what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 7):

You did not read your assignment properly:

> For each item in the food list, add **the price of that item** to total.

You are adding the item *itself*, not the *price* of the item.

You presumably have some means to find the price for each item, like a dictionary. You can't add the `'apple'` string, but if apples cost `0.10` (10 cents), then you *can* add `0.10` to `total`.

If you have a dictionary named `prices`, for example, you could just do:

```
prices = {
    'apple': 0.10,
    'pear': 0.15,
    'cumquat': 0.50,
}

def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        total += prices[item]
    return total
```

Note that I changed `x` to `item`, a more descriptive variable name that matches your assignment text.

Answer (score 2):

You should sum up the prices of each food, and not the food itself. Assuming you have a dictionary of prices, your code should be something like this:

```
def compute_bill(food):
  total = 0
  for x in food:
    total += prices[x]
return total
```

Comment: This is assuming that you have a dictionary of prices.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you: You cannot add up an integer and a string. This is because you are adding your total (an integer) and **the food itself**, instead of the price. You can fix this with: `your_dictionary[food]`, instead of just `food`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This the right code, it took me along time to fix it but make sure it looks similar to this :

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for each in food:
        total += prices[each]
    return total
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers are discouraged. Please try to provide some explanation for how your code solves the OPs problem. Also, you may want to read about [how to format your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). I have edited your answer to fix the code block.